# Sphinx: How can I change default ranking method?

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, sphinx

I have table of movies (movie_id, title), one movie can have many titles (different languages).
I would like to implement full-text search by all titles, then movies with the same relevance should be ordered by date. Now I’m using sphinx and doing this:

```
sql_joined_field = all_movie_titles from query; select movie_id as id, title      from tbl_movie_titles order by movie_id
```

It’s the only field which used for search
As I understand, in this way sphinx search matches of keyword in each title of one movie, but some movies have 2 titles, while another, for example, 10. Due to keywords often duplicates in different titles of one movie, sphinx calculate result relevance weight depends on matches in all titles of one movie. Because of this, two movies, which should have the same relevance have different weights. I’ve tried to use different rankers, but anyway results are bad. How can I make sphinx to calculate weight for each title of one movie independently and then take the highest?
If this task can be solved easier by another search engine, like elasticsearch tell me. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've effectively created a field that just contains **all** the titles concatenated as one long string (the 'joined' in the definition)

So multi-titled movie, will have the words multiple times, which as you say can affect ranking.

You seem to be currently setup to have your sphinx *document* as a movie. ie one document per movie (regardless of what data you have for the movie)

---

One options would be to change to instead have one *document* per title (ie movie/language **combination**), then the ranking will be 'within' the one language.

Because you (presumably) only want one **result** per movie, can use the query time `GROUP BY` option. (which means making sure you have `movie_id` as an `attribute`)